# Is there an official or de-facto common URN NID for private unregulated use?

Tags: naming-conventions, uri, standards, urn, iana

I would like to use URNs in a project of mine. And I am hardly willing to apply my humble project for official IANA registration but would like to keep from violating standards if possible. That's why I'd like to know if there is a standard (or de-facto common practice at least) NID to be placed instead of `private` in the following example:

```
urn:private:mycompany:myproject:mycollection:myresource
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [rfc2611](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2611.txt) you can define any NID you like so long as it starts with "X-". Such namespaces are considered experimental:

> No provision is made for avoiding collision of experimental
>   NIDs; they are intended for use within internal or limited
>   experimental contexts.
>
> As there is no registration, no registration maintenance
>   procedures are needed.

Comment: FYI, namespace id starting with 'X-' is no longer allowed, per [rfc8141](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8141#section-5.1)